# What is the answer?

Tags: logic-grid

Question 2
If two words are next to each other, they must share at least one letter and not be the same
length. There are six words below and the word on the far left is "CAT." Place all the words
in a way that satisfies the condition above.
List of words:
- cat (already used)
- win
- moon
- stop
- study
- rent

Answer (score 2):

The answer should be

> CA**T** S**T**OP S**T**UDY RE**NT** WI**N** MOO**N**

Comment: There's very limited possibilities, just tried things until it worked.